# cannot call native method eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse

I am developing an android app using C++ code. Trying using JNI but failed.
here is my code:
from test.c in jni folder:

```
jstring Segment_com_example_segment_BrowsePicture_test( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "test");
}
```

I already build by ndk and generate libtest.so.
but in my BrowsePicture.java (under Segment.com.example.segment) 
I added

```
public native String  test();
```

But I couldn't call it. 
the message is :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16748): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.segment.BrowsePicture.test:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

So can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

try with change method name by this...

```
jstring Java_com_example_segment_BrowsePicture_test( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
```

instead of this...

```
jstring Segment_com_example_segment_BrowsePicture_test( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
```

Comment: Good, and as I said you should really generate the jni function names by javah to avoid mistakes. See my previous comments for how to.

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared another class like the one below

```
package com.yourpackage;
public class NativeLib {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("yourlibrary");
}

public static native void your_function(your_arguments);
}
```

Then call this function from your activity using

```
NativeLib.your_function(your_arguments);
```

Comment: yes, I added     static {

           System.loadLibrary("test");
        } and I called this in my main activity. my make file is LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: is the name of method correct? I just follow the way Example Hello-jini did.

Comment: Create a another class instead of loading it in your MainActivity. And then call the method. Also see to it that the test.so is supported by the CPU architecture on which you are running. Else the test.so wont get installed and you will see this error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the lib by:

```
...
public class BrowsePicture {

    static {
        // assume that libtestjni.so is your lib file
        System.loadLibrary("testjni");
    }
...
```

Comment: yes, I did, my make file is  'LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)'   and I loaded  static { System.loadLibrary("test"); }

Comment: Did you include the .so file in your apk? (Place the .so file into the /libs/armeabi folder of your project and it will be packaged to the apk by ADT).

Comment: OK. I usually don't write the jni functions manually, instead I use javah to generate the .h file. First build the Android project (the java code), then start the command line window and change dir to your project folder, then run

"javah -classpath ./bin/classes -jni com.example.helloworld.MyJni"

and then you get the jni header file in the project folder (
com_example_helloworld_MyJni.h). You can generate your own .h file in the same way and include the file instead of writing your own function declaration.

Comment: alright, I will note this. Thanks alot. I am handling with many .cpp files